# Why does this SQL to split strings work with a comma delimited string but not a space delimited string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Using the SQL function provided in the Common Table Expression section of [this blog post](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) (copied below for convenience), I can split a comma separated string into a table containing each section of the string.

`SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitStrings_CTE('a,b,c', ',');` runs in a fraction of a second and returns the expected results. However, if I change the delimiter from a comma to a space, `SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitStrings_CTE('a b c', ' ');` never seems to finish executing. I've been trying to understand how the function works, but this aspect of it has me stumped. Why does it not seem able to handle using a space as a delimiter?

The function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_CTE
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS @Items TABLE (Item NVARCHAR(4000))
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ll INT = LEN(@List) + 1, @ld INT = LEN(@Delimiter);

   WITH a AS
   (
       SELECT
           [start] = 1,
           [end]   = COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, 1), 0), @ll),
           [value] = SUBSTRING(@List, 1, 
                     COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, 1), 0), @ll) - 1)
       UNION ALL
       SELECT
           [start] = CONVERT(INT, [end]) + @ld,
           [end]   = COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, [end] + @ld), 0), @ll),
           [value] = SUBSTRING(@List, [end] + @ld, 
                     COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, [end] + @ld), 0), @ll)-[end]-@ld)
       FROM a
       WHERE [end] < @ll
   )
   INSERT @Items SELECT [value]
   FROM a
   WHERE LEN([value]) > 0
   OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

   RETURN;
END
GO
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific. (Perhaps sql-server?)

Comment: Good shout, thanks. It is indeed SQL server I'm using.

Comment: probably bec `len(' ')=0 `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is why:

```
@ld INT = LEN(@Delimiter);
```

In Sql Server, `LEN` ignores trailing spaces - and when there is only one space, it's `LEN` will return `0`:

```
SELECT  LEN(',') As [LEN(',')], 
        LEN(N' ') As [LEN(N' ')], 
        LEN(N' 1') As [LEN(N' 1')], 
        LEN(N'1 ') As [LEN(N'1 ')]
```

Returns:

```
LEN(',')    LEN(N' ')   LEN(N' 1')  LEN(N'1 ')
1           0           2           1
```

To fix this, you can use `DATALENGTH`. However, since this is `NVARCHAR`, the `DATALENGTH` function will return the number of chars * 2, so you need to divide the result by 2:

```
@ld INT = DATALENGTH(@Delimiter)/2;
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/PLFN90006)

Comment: `LEN ignores trailing spaces` - I never knew that, suddenly it all makes sense! Thanks.